# Using keyboard keys to navigate a webpage (inside a content script)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like to start off by saying that I don't really need any code at this point. Most likely, i just need a starting point.

I am trying to build a browser extension(chrome) that will allow me to use keyboard keys to navigate one specific page.

This page is on a game (http://www.galatium.net/Faerlyn/forest.php?view=explore)
If you care to look, you'd have to sign up so i'll just describe it.

It's a 3x3 grid of clickable boxes (not really buttons...). The middle box is unclickable.

The game creator uses JS(onClick events) to navigate the area(interactive forest).

What I am trying to do is bind the onlick event for each box to a keyboard key.

Basically we have:

North=8
South=2
East=6
West=4
NorthWest=7
SouthWest=1
NorthEast=9
SouthEast=3

*Numpad Directions*

Now thru various research I have learned that I need to use a content script to inject my javascript onto the webpage I want this to work on.

The problem is that each box is dictated by this line of code:

`<td bgcolor="#002900" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(0, 41, 0);" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#003300'" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor='#002900'" onclick="window.location='?action=move&amp;x=332&amp;y=96'">&nbsp;</td>`

The line itself isn't too complicated, but I'm used to OOP, and I'm not understanding as to how I can refer to it.

This is how I'm thinking of doing it:

Say this is my JS function:

```
function DoSomething() {}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == arrow.left) {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

The code doesn't include it, but there will be a GET that will obtain the current X and Y values and then add or subtract one depending on the chosen direction.

So, `DoSomething()` will have a parameter called "direction".

and then  on the key press event, my function will "click" on the box that matches the X and Y of my function.

So, for north, first I have a get that finds x=10 and y=10. Then knowing that I have hit "8", it will set x=10 and y=10+1. The function will then find the box whose parameters match the params of my function, and "click" on it.

Am I doing this right? (Or is there an easier way?)

~Hamza

Comment: I have reworded my question. There is just one main question now. I haven't used this site in a long time, so can you tell me how to remove this hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `<table>`
In this table there are 3 `<tr>`
In each `<tr>` there are 3  containers

Giving you 13 selectable targets.

Using jQuery you can do several things:

You can assign each a unique `id` or `class`

keypress() action/select your key codes which are 96 through 105 on the number pad. You can map actions against the keypad.

Unclear are your actions s commits on moves.

Example: are you dealing with something that pops to the screen and then you quickly have to move it directionally? Direction keys but no commit keypress.

Example 2: you have a grid of movable prices like a puzzle but you have to bind a select before you engage direction and the unselect to freely navigate to another piece reselect...move...unselect...move...select.

Example 3: you need to do things in example 2 but you have to replace the tile and remember your origination spot to populate the removed peice. So the parts change location. Meaning you are given a set of pieces that cannot be destroyed. They can only change positions.

With the keypress and the key mapping and the unique id or class and select/unselect, you can bind a combination of things but you'll need to determine the event end result.

If you cannot use unique id or class on the table you can use parent, sibling, child jQuery selectors.

Next: what is inside the `<td>` ? Is it an image or background color? You can assign a css class/id that references the images or colors. That way you have your secondary selectors all figured out for moving, removing, holding or destroying, appending.

You can use either assigned class/id or parent , sibling, child to grab the contents of the container tags. From there you will have to answer for yourself what you are trying to do...end results. How a person wins or loses.